# R: Creating a generic function for ‘split’ from package ‘base’ in the global environment

Tags: r, generics, split, r-s4, r-s3

For simplicity, I will use the following sample code :)

I had defined a S4 class `test`, and then as usual I adopted `setMethod` to write generic function `split` for class `test`:

```
# define a S4 class
setClass(
  Class="test",
  representation=representation(
   m = "matrix"
  )
)

# write generic function 'split' for S4 class 'test'
setMethod(f = "split", signature = c("test"), function(x, f) {
  split(x@m, f)
})

# call generic function for test
split(new("test", m=matrix(1:9,3)), c(1,2,3))
```

Run the code above and the R command line will give out message as follows:

> Creating a generic function for ‘split’ from package ‘base’ in the global environment

and then the program output follows:

```
$`1`
[1] 1 4 7

$`2`
[1] 2 5 8

$`3`
[1] 3 6 9
```

It seems that output is correct. But my question is **how to supress the message:**

> Creating a generic function for ‘split’ from package ‘base’ in the global environment

Thanks a lot :)

**PS:**
I found that replace the definition of method `split` for S4 class `test` with the **form of how we realize S3 generic methods** as follows will do get rid of that *message*:

```
split.test <- function(x, f) {
  split(x@m, f)
}
```

However, I don't think it's a good idea to **mix S3 and S4**  :)

Comment: I wouldn't bet my family farm on this, but if you put the definitions into an R package, I would reckon the message would go away. On a side note, `suppressMessages()` seems to suppress the message.

Comment: You don't actually need to define a `split` method at all, really. Just define a method for `[`, and `split.default` will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unfortunate fact issue with S4 classes. The gold standard is frequently referred to as the `Matrix` package. They also cleverly avoid this issue: overloading `rownames` or `colnames` (defined in `base`) directly produces the identical warning. But inspection of these function reveals they are convenience functions to the `dimnames` function:

```
> colnames
function (x, do.NULL = TRUE, prefix = "col")
{
    if (is.data.frame(x) && do.NULL)
        return(names(x))
    dn <- dimnames(x)
# ...
}
> rownames
function (x, do.NULL = TRUE, prefix = "row")
{
    dn <- dimnames(x)
# ...
}
> dimnames
function (x)  .Primitive("dimnames")
```

The `Matrix` package avoids this issue by instead defining a generic against `dimnames`. As Michael above commented, your best bet is to overload the `[` operator, which is similarly primitive:

```
> `[`
.Primitive("[")
```

Borrowing from the `Matrix` package again, one suggestion would be:

```
setMethod("[", signature(x = "sparseMatrix", i = "missing", j = "index",
             drop = "logical"), 
    function(x, i, j, ..., drop) {
       # add any behavior for ...
       `[`(x@m, i, j, drop=drop)
    }
)
```

This also adds a lot of free behavior from other generic functions using the `[` operator.

Comment: I wonder how or if this would work for `View` within RStudio?